# Method to dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

In this example I want to do a menu with commands (add 2 numbers and sub 2 numbers). I would like to do this with a dictionary where I want to assign to the key value the method `add` and `sub`. When I call the method `UI`,the key values are called. How to fix it?

```
class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self):
        a = int(input("Number a is:"))
        b = int(input("Number b is:"))
        return a + b
    def sub(self):
        a = int(input("Number a is:"))
        b = int(input("Number b is:"))
        return a + b
    def UI(self):
        Options = {1:self.add(), 2:self.sub()}

n = Calc()
n.UI()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not adding function calls to dict's as it will likely just add confusion to your code.  However if you have to do it that way you can store the pointers to the functions.

```
    Options = {1:self.add,
               2:self.sub
              }
```

Which can than be called like

Options1

A quick working example based on your original code:

```
class Calc():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def add(self):
        a = int(input("Number a is:"))
        b = int(input("Number b is:"))
        return a + b
    def sub(self):
        a = int(input("Number a is:"))
        b = int(input("Number b is:"))
        return a + b
    def UI(self, option):
        Options = {1:self.add,
                   2:self.sub
                  }
        return Options[option]()

n = Calc()
n.UI(1)
Number a is:1
Number b is:1
2
```

Comment: if i have method with parameters ? def add(self,a,b): for example

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
    Options = {1:self.add(),
               2:self.sub()
              }
```

actually calls the `add` and `sub` methods *once* when the dictionary is created. You want the methods to be called when the user selects an option from the menu. You could do it with this as your `UI()` method instead:

```
    def UI(self):
        options = {1:self.add,
                   2:self.sub}
        while True:
            # get user selection
            selection = input("1. add\n2: subtract\nSelection: ")
            if selection.lower().startswith('q'):
               # any input starting with "Q" or "q" quits
               break
            # call method corresponding to the user's selection
            result = options[int(selection)]()
            # error handling omitted
            print("Result: {}".format(result))
```

P.S. your `sub()` method actually adds.

---

**Update**

You now require that the parameters for the various operations be passed to the method. This means that the parameters must be collected externally to the method. Here is one such way:

```
import operator

class Calc:
    def my_div(self, a, b):
        return a / float(b)    # ensure float division

    def UI(self):
        options = {1: operator.add,
                   2: operator.sub,
                   3: self.my_div,}

        while True:
            # get user selection
            selection = input("1. add\n2: subtract\n3: divide\nq: quit\nSelection: ")
            if selection.lower().startswith('q'):
               # any input starting with "Q" or "q" quits
               break

            selection = int(selection)
            if selection not in options:
                print("Invalid selection, try again")
                continue

            # get arguments to pass to operation
            a = int(input("Number a is:"))
            b = int(input("Number b is:"))

            # call method corresponding to the user's selection
            result = options[selection](a, b)
            # error handling omitted
            print("Result: {}".format(result))
```

It's optional, but you no longer need to define your own `add()`, `sub()`, etc. methods. You can simply use those provided by the `operator` module as shown above, or you can implement your own also as shown above.

This assumes that all operations require the same number of arguments. If that is not the case then you could set your dictionary to contain tuples with the function and required number of arguments:

```
options = {1: (operator.add, 2),
           2: (operator.sub, 2),
           3: (self.my_div, 2),
           4: (operator.neg, 1),    # N.B. unary operator
}
```

Then, when you get the arguments from the user:

```
# get arguments to pass to operation
function, n_args = options[selection]
args = [int(input("Number {} is:".format(i+1))) for i in range(n_args)]
```

Finally, call the method:

```
result = function(*args)
```

which will unpack the arguments and pass them into the corresponding function.

Comment: if i have method with parameters ?  def add(self,a,b):  for example

Comment: Well that's not what you show in your question. You should update your question to show your changed requirement. This will require collection of the arguments from the user before dispatching to the method. Do all of your methods accept the same number of arguments?

Comment: @paulc: updated answer to show how to handle functions with arguments. Also brief description about how to dispatch to a set of functions with different numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your dictionary to something like this:

```
options = {1:self.add, 2:self.sub}
```

so python does not call the methods when the dict is crated, but stores the method reference in `options` as values.

Now you can call (ie. execute) a method in `options` by calling

```
options[some_key]()
```

or (as you wanted)

```
options[1]() #add
options[2]() #sub
```